# How can I get info about the list View Item selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

```
           foreach (string imageFile in files)
           {
                try
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image myImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
                    myImageList.Images.Add(myImage);
                    myImage.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < myImageList.Images.Count; i++) //I have a list view containing images
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.ImageIndex = i;
                imageListView.Items.Add(item);
            }

            private void imageListView_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 string myImage = imageListView.SelectedItems.ToString(); //get the name of image selected
            }
```

Now I want to get the name of image when it is selected, something like above function of imageListView_Clicked():

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify this part of code to put name of image to its `Tag` property:

```
 foreach (string imageFile in files)
       {
            try
            {
                System.Drawing.Image myImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
                myImage.Tag="image name for each item";//you can put for example image file name
                myImageList.Images.Add(myImage);
                myImage.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

then when you want to get selected image's name you can use this code:

```
private void imageListView_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     String imgName= (String)imageListView.SelectedItems[0].ImageList.Images[0].Tag;

 }
```

Comment: `(String)myImageList.SelectedItems[0].ImageList.Images[0].Tag;` I don't think this works. the correct code should be `(String)imageListView.LargeImageList[myImageList.SelectedItems[0].ImageIndex].Tag;` However you should use the `Tag` of the `ListViewItem` itself rather than of its `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work.

```
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {

           MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        }
    }
```